# How to properly write a fade-out to a WAV file using NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav, naudio

I'm using NAudio to convert & trim some audio files, and I'm trying to add a fade-out to the last few seconds of each file.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24157428/4934172), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28861290/4934172), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17322052/4934172), but all the answers are talking about playing the wav file with fade, while I need to actually write that fade to an output file.

So, is there any way to do this using NAudio? If not, I'm open to other suggestions.

---

**Edit:** This is what I've tried:

```
private void PerformFadeOut(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    WaveFileReader waveSource = new WaveFileReader(inputPath);

    ISampleProvider sampleSource = waveSource.ToSampleProvider();

    OffsetSampleProvider fadeOutSource = new OffsetSampleProvider(sampleSource);
    // Assume the length of the audio file is 122 seconds.
    fadeOutSource.SkipOver = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);   // Hard-coded values for brevity

    // Two seconds fade
    var fadeOut = new FadeInOutSampleProvider(fadeOutSource);
    fadeOut.BeginFadeOut(2000);

    Player = new WaveOut();

    Player.Init(fadeOut);
    Player.Play();    
}
```

When I play the audio after applying the fade using `Player.Play()` -*as shown in the method above*-, it works perfectly as expected, and I can hear the fade. Now, I would like to export this result to an output WAV file.

I tried doing that by adding the following line:

```
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputPath, waveSource);
```

However, the output file doesn't have any fade applied to it. So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try with WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputPath, fadeOut); instead?

Comment: @yms `CreateWaveFile` method is expecting a second argument of type `IWaveProvider`. Apparently, `FadeInOutSampleProvider` class doesn't implement this interface, hence can't be casted.

Comment: Then WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(outputPath, fadeOut) or WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile( outputPath, new SampleToWaveProvider(fadeOut)). See here: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/SampleProviders/SampleToWaveProvider.cs and here: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveFileWriter.cs

Comment: @yms `CreateWaveFile16` doesn't work also because it expects the same type of arguments. But the second suggestion might actually work. Let me try it..

Comment: " it expects the same type of arguments" no it does not... at least not in the source code that pointed to: public static void CreateWaveFile16(string filename, ISampleProvider sourceProvider)

Comment: @yms Oh, my mistake. Both actually work fine. I can now see the fade in the output file, but since I now pass `fadeOut` instead of `waveSource`, the output file only has the last two seconds (which makes sense as we skipped over the rest). So..

Comment: I tried using the [`DelayFadeOutSampleProvider`](https://gist.github.com/markheath/8fb396a5fe4bf117f361) class proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876033/4934172) instead of `FadeInOutSampleProvider`. Now the whole file gets saved, but it misses up the fading position *(only when saving though, **Not** if I played it internally!)*. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153408/discussion-between-ahmed-abdelhameed-and-yms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Okay, let's wrap everything up in case someone encounters the same issue in the future:**

With the great help of @yms, I managed to write the fade to a file by using:

```
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputPath, new SampleToWaveProvider(fadeOut));
```

But that caused the wave writer to only write the last two seconds *which makes sense*, so I tried using the [`DelayFadeOutSampleProvider`](https://gist.github.com/markheath/8fb396a5fe4bf117f361) class instead of `FadeInOutSampleProvider`. With that I was able to write the whole file, but it ended up causing the fading to start in a wrong position (*it's more obvious when saving though. **Not** when playing*).

I generated a 10 seconds wav file with Audacity, and used the following method for testing:

```
private static void PerformFadeOut(string inputPath, string outputPath, bool playNoSave = false)
{
    WaveFileReader waveSource = new WaveFileReader(inputPath);

    ISampleProvider sampleSource = waveSource.ToSampleProvider();

    // Two seconds fade
    var fadeOut = new DelayFadeOutSampleProvider(sampleSource);
    fadeOut.BeginFadeOut(8000, 2000);

    if(playNoSave)
    {
        // Here the fade is played exactly where expected (@00:08)
        var player = new WaveOut();
        player.Init(fadeOut);
        player.Play();
    }
    else
    {
        // But when saving, the fade is applied @00:04!
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputPath, new SampleToWaveProvider(fadeOut));
    }
}
```

Here's the file, before & after writing the fade-out:

[image: Before & after writing the fade-out]

As shown above, the fade-out doesn't start at the right position.

After some investigation in the `DelayFadeOutSampleProvider`, I found a bug in the `Read` method, so I modified it like this:

```
public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int sourceSamplesRead = source.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    lock (lockObject)
    {
        if (fadeOutDelaySamples > 0)
        {
            int oldFadeOutDelayPos = fadeOutDelayPosition;
            fadeOutDelayPosition += sourceSamplesRead / WaveFormat.Channels;
            if (fadeOutDelayPosition > fadeOutDelaySamples)
            {
                int normalSamples = (fadeOutDelaySamples - oldFadeOutDelayPos) * WaveFormat.Channels;
                int fadeOutSamples = (fadeOutDelayPosition - fadeOutDelaySamples) * WaveFormat.Channels;
                // apply the fade-out only to the samples after fadeOutDelayPosition
                FadeOut(buffer, offset + normalSamples, fadeOutSamples);

                fadeOutDelaySamples = 0;
                fadeState = FadeState.FadingOut;
                return sourceSamplesRead;
            }
        }
        if (fadeState == FadeState.FadingIn)
        {
            FadeIn(buffer, offset, sourceSamplesRead);
        }
        else if (fadeState == FadeState.FadingOut)
        {
            FadeOut(buffer, offset, sourceSamplesRead);
        }
        else if (fadeState == FadeState.Silence)
        {
            ClearBuffer(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }
    return sourceSamplesRead;
}
```

And now everything works just fine.

[Here's my fork](https://gist.github.com/Ahmed-Abdelhameed/b867a8cfe739cd7a128b73a33d317402) of the whole class if someone is interested, and I already asked the author (@mark-heath) to update the original gist with this fix.

Answer (score 1):

You original code was using the original `waveSource` as input, which is why you had no fade.

The following alternative uses the `fadeOut` object:

```
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(outputPath, fadeOut);
```

The signature of `CreateWaveFile16` would be:

```
public static void CreateWaveFile16(string filename, ISampleProvider sourceProvider)
```

This can be seen in the [source code of the class WaveFileWriter](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveFileWriter.cs).

Another alternative is to use the class [SampleToWaveProvider](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/SampleProviders/SampleToWaveProvider.cs) and covert your `fadeOut` object into an `IWaveProvider`, and that allows you to use the regular `CreateWaveFile` method.

```
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputPath, new SampleToWaveProvider(fadeOut))
```

As you know, in all cases your output file will only contain the last k seconds corresponding to the fadeout, a different class is needed if you want the whole file **with** a fadeout.

Comment: Thank you very much, you put me on the right track. I really appreciate your help. Upvoted, and will be awarding the bounty once it's possible.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I am glad it helped